# How to preventDefault and disable a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

On first click my button click function works, but upon clicking again it refreshes the page click the unbind isn't recognized. I need to prevent any default click event as well as disable the button after click.

```
<a href="" class="red-btn2">Save this Property</a>

$(".red-btn2").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).unbind('click');
  $(this).css({
    'background-color':'#666666',
    'text-align':'center'
  });
  $(this).text("Added to Favorites");
});
```

Comment: You unbind the click event.... of course it will not have anything attached to it so it will be a link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the rest of the handler to run only once, but `preventDefault()` always, you can separate them into multiple handlers.

Then, one of them can be removed after its first use (using jQuery's [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) will cover that for you), still leaving the `preventDefault()` in use:

```
$('.red-btn2')
    .click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    })
    .one('click', function () {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color':'#666666',
        'text-align':'center'
      });
      $(this).text("Added to Favorites");
    });
```

As you have it, the `event.preventDefault()` is being removed as well by `.unbind('click')`, so no functions are left on the element to call it for the 2nd click.

Comment: I understand now thank you. I had initially used .unbind successfully, before realizing I needed to add preventDefault which resulted in my conflict. This solution works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you unbind the handler, the button will function as normal on any subsequent click, and initiate a navigation. So you better really set the disabled property:

```js
$(".red-btn2").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).prop('disabled')) return; // <---
  $(this).prop('disabled', true); // <----
  $(this).css({
    'background-color':'#666666',
    'text-align':'center'
  });
  $(this).text("Added to Favorites");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="red-btn2">Save this Property</a>
```

Note that `event.preventDefault()` actually works. It was only on the second click you had issues, because the link was still clickable, but your function was detached from it, so you had no control over that second click.

Comment: Subsequently I added a line to update some div text:     $('#growl').append('Success'); This keeps repeating each time after my initial click so it seems like .prop('disabled',true) doesn't work for some reason. http://codepen.io/torch/pen/vyGJNb

Comment: Indeed. Fixed that just now. Add an `if` testing the disabled property, and exit when it is true, but only after preventing the default behaviour.

Comment: Excellent. Learning a lot tonight, this was definitely helpful.